# Where is gitweb.conf on Windows?

Tags: git, repository, egit, gitweb

I'm trying to setup GitWeb, I'm using the GitWeb shipped with the Git installation and using the Apache provided with WAMP, when I access to the page `http://localhost/gitweb/` I get a `404 - No projects found` error, I modified the variable `projectroot` on the `gitweb.cgi` file but according to some post this file shouldn't be edited and I need to modify the same variable but now on the file gitweb.conf and I can find this file, I tried with

```
gitweb.conf
gitweb-common.conf
gitweb_config.perl
```

I don't have any of those files, any ideas? BTW I'm working on Windows

I modified the next variables on gitweb.cgi

```
our $GIT = "C:/Git190/bin/git";
our $projectroot = "C:/git/testRepository/.git";
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, I just modified the `gitweb.cgi` and the problem was with the path of the `$projectroot` variable, I had it like this:

```
our $projectroot = "C:/git/testRepository/.git";
```

but I need to set the value like this:

```
our $projectroot = "/c/git/testRepository";
```

I have no idea why, but it's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [CIOC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2596007/cioc)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22180416/6309), it is best to use Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), [batch 10](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b50a608ba20348cb3dfc16a696816d51780e3f0f).

If your gitweb configuration exists, but is unreadable, `gitweb` behaved as if the file did not exist at all, but now it errors out.

See [commit ac62a36](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ac62a3649fcfd7f2caa80ffdfb8c3135764291ef) (10 Jan 2024) by [Marcelo Roberto Jimenez (`mrjimenez`)](https://github.com/mrjimenez).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b700f11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b700f119d183423916be7b8b0a2d48970cdf20e5), 26 Jan 2024)</sup>

> ### [`gitweb`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ac62a3649fcfd7f2caa80ffdfb8c3135764291ef): die when a configuration file cannot be read
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Marcelo Roberto Jimenez</sup>

> Fix a possibility of a permission to access error go unnoticed.
>
> Perl uses two different variables to manage errors from a "do $filename" construct.
> One is `$@`, which is set in this case when do is unable to compile the file.
> The other is `$!`, which is set in case do cannot read the file.
> The current code only checks "`$@`", which means a configuration file passed to GitWeb that is not readable by the server process does not cause it to "`die`".
>
> Make sure we also check and act on "`$!`" to fix this.